# Body response to client(Angular2) from Node API via Express formatted wrong

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular, express

When my Angular2 component makes a request to get my fake model data object it gets returned like so:

`_body: "[↵  {↵    "id": 0,↵    "title": "2017 Oscars",↵    "graphic": "https://wikitags.com/images/OscarsBanner.png",↵`

[image]

What I am expecting is an Array like so:

```
[ 
  { id: 0,
    title: '2017 Oscars',
    graphic: '/images/OscarsBanner.png',
    categorycards: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { id: 1,
    title: '2017 Super Bowl',
    graphic: '/images/SuperBowlBanner.png',
    categorycards: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { id: 2,
    title: 'What people are talking about',
    graphic: null,
    categorycards: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } 
]
```

---

#### The Model

What my `backend/models/home.ts` looks like

```
export function homeData() {
    return [
        {
            id: 0,
            title: '2017 Oscars',
            graphic: '/images/OscarsBanner.png',
            categorycards: [
                {
                    type: 'image',
                    graphic: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Ryan_Gosling_2_Cannes_2011_%28cropped%29.jpg/1024px-Ryan_Gosling_2_Cannes_2011_%28cropped%29.jpg?width=440',
                    title: '2017 Oscar Nominee for Best Actor',
                    listings: ['Rayn Gosling', 'Denzel Washington', 'Andrew Garfield', 'Casey Affleck', 'Viggo Mortensen']
                }
                //...
            ]
        }
        //...
    ];
}
```

#### The client API

`api.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    private getFeaturedUrl: string = '/wiki/api';

    constructor(public http: Http) {}

    /**
     * Get featured categories data for homepage
     */
    getFeatured(): Observable<{}> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.getFeaturedUrl}/home`)
        .do(res => console.log('getFeatured res', res))
        .map(res => res.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

The `console.log` here:

[image]

#### The homepage component

```
universalInit() {
    console.log('universalInit...')
    this.api.getFeatured()
        .subscribe(categories => {
            console.log('categories', categories);
            // this.testFeaturedCategories = categories
        });
```

#### The Node/Express API endpoint

```
// API CRUD ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
app.get('/wiki/api/home', (req, res) => {
    console.log('homeData()', homeData());
    if (!homeData()) returnError(res, 'No home data found');
    res.json(homeData());
});
```

In the terminal, I see my `home.ts` model Array:

[image]

Any ideas why my res.body is looking jacked up?

Comment: ↵ is the return character. Try removing the newlines on the backend (i.e. try returning {id: 0, title...} in one line and see what happens. Alternatively, try replacing ↵ in the response with '\n' on the client with the string.replace method (see documentation if you don't know how to use it).

Comment: Everything has to be on 1 line? That is going to make an unreadable test model, but I'll try it out.

Comment: I'd prefer just replacing all the ↵s with '\n's on the client side.

Comment: Ok I just tried every thing on 1 line, and the Response is still the same. Also the key is wrong, says `_body` instead of `body` would that be an indicator that something else is going wrong?

Comment: what do you get when you console.log() res.json() instead of res?

Comment: The res.json() returned what I expected and what the log in the express API was showing me too. Looks like I was double res.jsoning it.

Comment: Right, I saw BRogers' answer later. Things like this seem obvious later but can be difficult to notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it may be trying to convert the json object twice. Not completely sure though

instead of `res.json(homeData())`

Try:

`res.send(homedata())`

If that doesn't work, then my guess would be to go on the angular side and change

`.map(JSON.parse(res.json().data))`

Comment: Ah that was it! Yeah I did a res.json in Express and in Angular, I'm getting the data in correctly as a formatted Array of Objects now :D

Comment: Great stuff! Glad it's working for you! I've came across that one before and wanted to face-plant on my keyboard.